# How do I login to a website and print the source?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, python-requests

How do I login to www.###.nl/admin and print the source?

I've tried several things.

Here's what I tried recently using requests:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.###.nl/admin"
r = requests.get(url, auth=('***', '***'))
page = r.text

print(page)
```

This code just prints out the code of the login page.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look at the source code for the page... There's a form - look at where the `action=` points to on that, and take note of what `name=` the form elements have for username and password. Then issue a `requests.post` with that data to the form processing URL and keep your fingers crossed that's all you need to do.

Comment: it is probably a good idea to collect **all** form elements inside that form or you might miss stuff like csrf tokens. Use lxml oder BeautifulSoup for that - then add the key->value for everything else as well as the username and pw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using [Splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/).

[Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) (headless WebKit) is used as the browser. You can also use other browsers, check out the [documentation](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/browser.html) for Splinter.

This is the working code:

```
from splinter import *
from selenium import *

username1 = '***'
password1 = '***'

browser1 = Browser('phantomjs')
browser1.visit('http://***.nl/admin')
browser1.fill('username', username1)
browser1.fill('password', password1)
browser1.click_link_by_text('Inloggen')

url1 = browser1.url
title1 = browser1.title

titlecheck1 = 'Dashboard'

print "Step 1 (***):"

if title1 == titlecheck1:
    print('Succeeded')

else:
    print('Failed')
    browser1.quit()

print 'The source is:'
print browser1.html

browser1.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the source of this page, and identify the form element that is being submitted (you can use Chrome Developer Tools for this purpose). You can then find the `input` elements and identify the required `name` attributes.

An example (untested):

```
import requests
payload = {
'username': 'USERNAME', 
'password': 'PASSWORD'
}
url = 'http://www.fonexshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=common/login'
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print r.text
```

Check the documentation for Requests library [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

**UPDATE** (if the site uses cookies)

From the [documentation wiki](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/),

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across
>   requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the
>   Session instance.

Here's another example:

```
from requests import session

payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'username': USERNAME,
    'password': PASSWORD
}

with session() as c:
    c.post('http://www.fonexshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=common/login', data=payload)
    request = c.get('http://www.fonexshop.nl/the/page/you/want/to/view/source/for.php')
    print request.headers
    print request.text
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: This is a great answer.

Unfortunately the python code gives me the source code of the login page.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Amal.

Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I can't accept an answer that doesn't work.

Comment: @narek_a: It's okay. But nobody is going to give you the exact script that works. You'll have to play with it, test it, and see what works and what doesn't. We're just helping :)

Comment: @narek_a Check carefully that there's no other information in the page that's returned that could indicate something useful about why the site's not accepting your login...

Comment: the html source shows that `enctype=multipart/form-data` is required. [`files` parameter could be used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17287715/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Find out whether you need javascript to login or to see the data (disable javascript in the browser and try to login manually). If javascript is required then you could use something like [Selenium Webdriver](http://blog.likewise.org/2013/04/webdriver-testing-with-python-and-ghostdriver/) to get page with a javascript-generated content. Or use a network sniffer such as `wireshark` to find out what requests exactly your browser sends and then try to replicate them using `requests` library.

You could start with sending a post request using [`multipart/form-data`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data) content type that you could see in the html source of `/admin` page. Building on [@Amal Murali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284131/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from requests import session  # pip install requests

credentials = dict(username='your username', password='your password')
login_url = 'http://www.fonexshop.nl/admin/index.php?route=common/login'

with session() as s:
    r = s.post(login_url, files=credentials)
    # print some debugging info
    print("Post status: {}".format(r.status_code), file=sys.stderr)
    print(r.headers, file=sys.stderr)
    print("Cookies: {}".format(dict(r.cookies)), file=sys.stderr)

    r = s.get('http://www.fonexshop.nl/' + 'path you actually want')
    print("Get status: {}".format(r.status_code), file=sys.stderr)
    print(r.headers, file=sys.stderr)
    print(r.text) # print the web page source to stdout
```

Note: `files` is used instead of `data` to generate `multpart/form-data` request instead of `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. I got it to work using Splinter (a test framework for web applications).